# Pandas: get the difference from the previous row for a given column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
countryname  yr  US_Election_Year   id_score       Dem_Score
  Albania   1992    1990            0.688809        0.366570                        
  Albania   1997    1996            0.024751        0.247750            
  Argentina 1995    1992            0.081818        0.398908            
  Argentina 1999    1996            -0.521796       0.247759
  Argentina 2003    2000            -0.293386       -0.102298
```

What I am trying to do is to take the difference between `id_score` and next row value of `Dem_Score` i.e.

```
id_score in ith row - Dem_Score in i+1 row for a given countryname
```

Eg. for the `countryname` Argentina and for the `yr` 1999, the desired difference would be

```
0.081818 - 0.247759 = -0.165941
```

So the final dataframe should look like below:

```
countryname yr  US_Election_Year    id_score    Dem_Score   Delta_Dem_Dist
  Albania   1992    1990            0.688809    0.366570                            
  Albania   1997    1996            0.024751    0.247750        0.441130
  Argentina 1995    1992            0.081818    0.398908                    
  Argentina 1999    1996            -0.521796   0.247759        -0.165941   
  Argentina 2003    2000            -0.293386   -0.102298       -0.624094
```

So a simple `df['id_score'] - df['Dem_Score'].shift(-1)` may not work.

Any clue on how to get the above approach for a given country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Delta_Dem_Dist'] = df.groupby('countryname').apply(lambda x: x['id_score'].shift(1) - x['Dem_Score']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
  countryname    yr  US_Election_Year  id_score  Dem_Score  Delta_Dem_Dist
0     Albania  1992              1990  0.688809   0.366570             NaN
1     Albania  1997              1996  0.024751   0.247750        0.441059
2   Argentina  1995              1992  0.081818   0.398908             NaN
3   Argentina  1999              1996 -0.521796   0.247759       -0.165941
4   Argentina  2003              2000 -0.293386  -0.102298       -0.419498
```

This code groups the dataframe by `countryname`, applies a lambda function to calculate the difference between `id_score` and the next row’s `Dem_Score` for each group, and then resets the index of the resulting dataframe.

And I think you made a small mistake in the last calculation in your desired output, I believe it should be `-0.419498` instead of `-0.624094`

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'countryname': ['Albania', 'Albania', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Argentina'],
               'yr': [1992, 1997, 1995, 1999, 2003],
               'US_Election_Year': [1990, 1996, 1992, 1996, 2000],
               'id_score': [0.688809, 0.024751, 0.081818, -0.521796, -0.293386],
               'Dem_Score': [0.366570, 0.247750, 0.398908, 0.247759, -0.102298]})

def g(df):
    df['Delta_Dem_Dist'] = df['id_score']-df.groupby('countryname')['Dem_Score'].shift(-1)
    df.loc[df.groupby('countryname')['Dem_Score'].transform('idxmin'), 'Delta_Dem_Dist'] = None
    df['Delta_Dem_Dist'] = df['Delta_Dem_Dist'].shift(1)
    return df

df = g(df.copy())
print(df)
```

However, the expected output given by you is wrong in last row it should be -0.419498

Answer (score 0):

use `groupby` + `shift`

```
df['Delta_Dem_Dist'] = df.groupby('countryname')['id_score'].shift().sub(df['Dem_Score'])
```

df

[image]